# resourceView in fullcalendar in basicView

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I use this script http://ikelin.github.io/fullcalendar/example.html with fullcalendar. It works, but i would like to display only the "all-day" slot and not all of "minutes" slot (as the "basicDayView").

Is someone already do that ? I try to modify the code of fullcalendar.js but it doesn't work.
Can you help me please ?

Have a good day !
(ps : sorry for my english)

Comment: What have you tried so far. Can you narrow this down to a specific issue you are having with some code we can help you with

Answer (score 0):

Depends of what you want, if you want to show an event that covers all day you have to do something like this:

```
...
events:[{
  start: 2014-01-07 06:00:00,
  end: 2014-01-07 23:59:00,
  allDay: false
 }]
...
```

If you want only an event that shows only allDay in the allDay event slot of dayview

```
...
events:[{
  start: 2014-01-07,
  end: 2014-01-07,
  allDay: true
 }]
...
```